# Full Format New 5 TB WD HDD external after 95% there is power outage

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, power-supply, wd

Full Format New 5 TB WD HDD external after 95% (after 60 hours of format) there is power outage so it fail to finish then i power on the laptop then use quick format to do format. Should i be worry if there is damage or bad sector or anything?
Should I do another full format.
(My first one fail at 40% because power outage and second ones at 95% same reason) i choose quick format because worry for another outage.

Comment: AFAIK full format really just means to zero-fill the sectors that are not yet need to be written in a quick format. (In other words it's pretty pointless for a new drive.) If a bad sector has been caused by the power outage, it wouldn't be due to a formation particularly (but really because things are flying inside your drive for whatever data write it is; and you can't exactly repair a bad sector with full format)

Comment: I see. I just thinking full format new HDD external good. Like clean everything and start new no bad sector etc like fragging etc

Comment: That's already been done at the factory before they shipped it. There is absolutely no point to full format a new drive.

Comment: oh, BTW, when you format it, format it with something at least with rudimentary journaling, as you have so many outages. *Nothing with the word FAT in it*. NTFS at minimum. [Windows doesn't really have a fully journaled native format, so that's the best]. Non-journaled volumes can fail catastrophically in a power-cut.

Comment: @Tetsujin, perhaps I'm overly cautious, but when I buy an expensive large format drive I intend to use for 5 years, I always full format it before use, so that it attempts to write to the entirety of the disk, and has that oportunity to encounter any bad sectors, and then check the smart stats. after that I run chkdsk in thorough mode, so it can reallocate any pending sectors, and check the stats again. if there are more than 1 or 2 raw read errors, pending, uncorrectable, or reallocated sectors, then back to the store it goes. I've had to return 2 drives over the years for that reason.

Comment: @Tetsujin what about the installed management software some drives come with?  Would not formatting in that case actually clean things up a small bit?  (Don't know the answer, that's why I came to the question!)

Comment: @FrankThomas - I've had so few drives ever fail during service [& SSDs are winning that race] that I don't consider it a valuable use of my time.

Comment: @JeopardyTempest - I've never bought a drive with anything on it. Copy if off to the internal if you want it. Quick format the drive. Other than for security reasons, you don't need unused sectors to be 'neat', just unused.

Answer (score 7):

In quick format, only the data is "deleted" by re-initializing the
partition table as empty.
This only touches upon a very small area at the head of the disk.

Full format involves re-writing every bit of the disk and leaves
the disk in the same state as in quick format. Its purpose is
to renew the magnetism of an old and weak disk and detect
failing sectors.

Normally a new disk does not need to be fully formatted, because the
factory format was much more thorough and extensive than anything
you can do on your computer. In most cases, even a quick format
is not required.

The format was interrupted in your case once, with no harm done,
then a second time. It certainly only interrupted, if anything, the
disk head from rewriting to the disk some bits while refreshing the
magnetism. This is useless for a new disk, and is only counseled
for an old and tired disk.

I would say that your chances are 99.99% that no harm was done by the
power failure. Modern disks are protected against power failure
and can terminate safely the current operation.
Even in the case that the one sector that was being written at the
time was corrupted by the interruption, you may have as result
one bad sector on the disk, which is nothing at all.

In conclusion, there is no need to start a third full format.

On the other hand, power interruptions can be extremely harmful, up to
destroying the ability of Windows to boot. If they are so frequent
at your place, I would suggest buying a UPS that can automatically
and gracefully turn off the computer in case of a power failure.

Comment: `re-initializing the partition table as containing one partition whose file system is empty` that has nothing to do with formation. Formation refers to the (re)creation of a filesystem, not partition table. `magnetic signature address` makes no sense to me. If you are talking about LBA to sector mapping, neither type of format itself would cause any change to that. If the drive controller decides to "relocate a sector" because it detected a bad sector or whatever, that's what it does behind the scene for that particular sector / reason, not because full format can instruct anything similar.

Comment: @TomYan: I put in less details, since there is no point in discussing here what exactly happens for a full format, and in any case different utilities might format differently.

Comment: @TomYan For "magnetic sector address", very old hard drives that used stepper motors re-wrote sector/address information as part of a low-level format, very similar to formatting a floppy disk. This was thoroughly obsolete by the 1990's, as voice coil based hard drives could only be low level formatted with [special equipment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servowriter) at the factory. As an aside, the Zip disk was an extension of this concept to floppies.

Comment: @user71659 To be frank, I have no idea why people still even talks about "low-level format" these days, but the real problem is, while I am not old enough to tell exactly how things were back in my childhood (Win98), in modern days (AFAIK post-XP give or take) full format, if it ever had, has nothing to do with that, neither is that a thing anymore in modern HDDs to normal user. And you know what, it's fine to be nostalgic. What irritates me is when talking about history becomes a reason / cause of mixing everything up. (But meh, I suppose that's just an excuse. See the PT vs FS case above.)

Answer (score 2):

Following @harrymc's reply.  I would recommend that you run chkdsk from the command line.  This is because it may have been interrupted part-way in an operation that could have corrupted the disk formatting.  It should also find any hard-errors if they have been produced because of the power fail.

```
chkdsk Drive /F/X
```

This will fix any errors (F) and dismount the drive if necessary (X).

Comment: I wonder whether in any corner case that's a better thing to do than a quick (re-)format, given that no data has been written to the perhaps-broken filesystem yet. (I admit I biasedly consider chkdsk crap, heh.)

Comment: @TomYan - A full format would have been writing to every "sector".  If the power failed while doing this, that particular spot may have incorrect data/header information or it may even have been damaged.  With what tools are on already on Windows, I would suggest that chkdsk would be prudent.  I don't regard it as a comprehensive test, but it may find something to fix / mark off.